# Iron.io set up getting 404 Not Found on `iron register` step

Tags: docker, iron.io

I am working through the iron.io getting started guide here: http://dev.iron.io/worker/getting_started/

I am at the step:

```
Push it to Docker Hub and register your image with Iron:

docker push USERNAME/hello:0.0.1
iron register USERNAME/hello:0.0.1
```

The `docker push` command works as intended, but when I run `iron register USERNAME/hello:0.0.1` I get the following response:

```
----->  Configuring client
        Project '' with id='5af78**********9198850e'
----->  Registering worker 'USERNAME/hello:0.0.1'
404 Not Found: Endpoint not found
```

Why it is returning 404 Not Found?

I notice that the project name is not written in the command line response, I think it could be related but I don't know where to update that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you don't have credentials configured.

There is a `Before you begin` section on the `Getting started` page with a link to [Setup your Iron.io credentials](http://dev.iron.io/worker/reference/configuration/)

You need to have a proper `iron.json` file or setup environment variables to set a project and a token.

> Note: `404 Not Found: Endpoint not found` and `Project ''` comes in case of invalid project_id in the iron.json file. Make sure that your project_id correct.

Comment: thanks for the answer, unfortunately that does not appear to be the problem.  I do have an iron.json file, I didn't have the global vars configured previously but I tried again after adding them and got the same result

Comment: Just checked it on my installation following every step in `Getting started`. I'm getting `404 Not Found: Endpoint not found` and `Project ''` only when using invalid project_id in the `iron.json` file. Make sure that your project_id correct.